# Which GAE Database Property Fits a Tag Property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to have a property on a database model of mine in Google App Engine and I am not sure which category works the best.  I need it to be a tag cloud similar to the Tags on SO.  Would a text property be best or should I use a string property and make it repeated=True.

The second seems best to me and then I can just divide the tags up with a comma as a delimiter.  My goal is to be able to search through these tags and count the total number of each type of tag.

Does this seem like a reasonable solution?

Comment: Have a look at the Python Search API to find out how to create searchable documents: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of interest, depending on exactly what you want to do.

[GAE Sharding Counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)

> When developing an efficient application on Google App Engine, you need to pay attention to how often an entity is updated. While App Engine's datastore scales to support a huge number of entities, it is important to note that you can only expect to update any single entity or entity group about five times a second. That is an estimate and the actual update rate for an entity is dependent on several attributes of the entity, including how many properties it has, how large it is, and how many indexes need updating. While a single entity or entity group has a limit on how quickly it can be updated, App Engine excels at handling many parallel requests distributed across distinct entities, and we can take advantage of this by using sharding.
>
> The question is, what if you had an entity that you wanted to update
>   faster than five times a second? For example, you might count the
>   number of votes in a poll, the number of comments, or even the number
>   of visitors to your site.

So you would create a tag like:

```
increment(tag)
```

which also happens to create it if it does not exist.

To count

```
get_count(tag)
```

But yes, you can make a repeated property which is a list essentially and store that and load it and count the values in it. It depends on how many you are going to have as the datastore has a limit on the model size and if you store it in a single model in a single list it'll eventually be too large.

So perhaps one model per tag, all of a single type? And when you run into the problem of 5/sec the above will come in handy.

Comment: thanks for the information.  I should only have 5 or so tags per model and then thousands of models but there isn't a limit on the number of models so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

A repeated string property is your best option.

Comment: Because he's trying to store a list of tags - which are text strings.